# After removing and putting back SSD windows not booting

Tags: windows, boot, ssd

I had to temporary replace my SSD to another one on my laptop. Now I have put back my old SSD back in, and it doesnt find windows boot manager. However, if i put this SSD into external case and then boot from USB, it boots up windows fine, so everything is fine with SSD disk itself, it alsdo boots up windows fine from replacement SSD as well. Any Ideas what can be wrong?

Comment: With the old SSD inside, boot into the BIOS, see if it's listed, and try to set it as the boot device.

Comment: It is listed, computer sees it normally, but somehow it doesnt boot from it (tho as I said it does boot when I connect old SSD via USB)

Comment: What did you do with the SSD while it was out of the old computer? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)